# Populate SwiftyPickerPopover choices with array

Tags: ios, swift3, uiactionsheet

I'm using [SwiftyPickerPopover](https://github.com/hsylife/SwiftyPickerPopover) to display popup control in order for user to select a value. Previously at another place in the app I've implemented it as:

```
let displayStringFor:((String?)->String?)? = { string in
            if let s = string {
                switch(s){
                case "Lhe”:
                    return "Lh”
                case "Khi":
                    return "Khi”
                case "Isb”:
                    return "Isb"
                case "Guj":
                    return "Guj"
                default:
                    return s
                }
            }
            return nil
        }

        let p = StringPickerPopover(title: "Select City", choices: ["Lhe”,”Khi”,”Isb”,”Guj”])
            .setDisplayStringFor(displayStringFor)
            .setDoneButton(
                action: {  popover, selectedRow, selectedString in

                    self.cityButton.setTitle(selectedString,for: .normal)
                    if selectedRow == 0 {
                        self.cityImage.image = UIImage(named: "Lhe")
                    } else if selectedRow == 1 {
                        self.cityImage.image = UIImage(named: "Khi")
                    } else if selectedRow == 2 {
                        self.cityImage.image = UIImage(named: "Isb")
                    } else if selectedRow == 3 {
                        self.cityImage.image = UIImage(named: "Guj")
                    }
            })
            .setCancelButton(action: {_, _, _ in
            })
        p.appear(originView: sender as! UIView, baseViewController: self)
```

Which you can see the values are hardcoded here. Now I've an API that gives me all the cities. So I made `var mainCitiesArray = [City]()` and called the API and parsed data to it.

In `mainCitiesArray` I've all the cities now which I want to display in this popup. How can I do that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do you need just to parse the cities names to string array?

E.G.

```
let citiesNamesArray = mainCitiesArray.map({
    (city: City) -> String in
    return city.name
})
```

And you can pass `citiesNamesArray` to `choises` parameter.